# How to import excel data to laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

How to import excel, with data like this

[image]

i use laravel, with condition if data have same value become 1 data in database. i use maatwebsite/excel as dependency in laravel

Comment: you check it https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html

Comment: use ToModel or ToCollection?

Comment: @YogaArliza please explain the condition? And what results do you expect?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto this import thing for sales order, in the excel file have 2 data, 1. Customer data, and 2. Product data. if count columns find the same number or another columns find same value, it will be 1 data in database. and for product data, it will find relation for it